# Using while loops with for loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2=[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
l3=[]
new_list=[]
i=1
while i<8:
    for num in l2:
        l3.append(num*i)
        i+=1
new_list.append(l3)
print(new_list)
```

How do I convert this into a list comprehension?

```
    new_list=[new_list.append(num*i) while(i<8) for num in l2 i+=1]
```

Expected Output:

```
 new_list = [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343]
```

Comment: share your expected output

Comment: `[num*i for i, num in enumerate(l2, 1)]`,  If you needed it as a nested list, `[[num*i for i, num in enumerate(l2, 1)]]`

Comment: @r.ook "i" starts with 1

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes I missed that, edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way:

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2=[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
new_list = [i*j for i,j in zip(l1, l2)]
print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
[i*n for i, n in zip(range(1,8), l2)]
```

Or `itertools.starmap` and `operator.mul`: *(Don't forget to import them)*

```
list(starmap(mul, zip(range(1,8), l2)))
```

Both will result in the same output:

```
from itertools import groupby, starmap, product
from operator import itemgetter, mul

l1 = range(1,8)
l2=[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]

new_list1 = [i*n for i, n in zip(l1, l2)]
new_list2 = list(starmap(mul, zip(l1, l2)))

print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
```

---

Results:

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343]
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343]
```

Comment: Why do you make the result a nested list in both approaches?

Comment: Because OP's result is a nested list.

Comment: Just noticed they edited to show their expected results